# No Internet on Ubuntu 16.4.6 LTS

Tags: networking

Running Ubuntu on a VM with a static ip. I can ping other servers on the lan but not google. I cannot see the file resolv.conf

```
root@idp1:/etc# cat /etc/resolv.conf
cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory

root@idp1:/etc# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 أغس 27 09:49 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Not sure if the file is deleted. Can someone help me with this?

---

Tried what you suggested, did not receive any errors.

```
root@idp1:/etc# rm /etc/resolv.conf
root@idp1:/etc# ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
root@idp1:/etc# shutdown -r
```

After restart, I can ping ip addresses but not hostnames.

```
idp@idp1:~$ ping www.du.edu.om
ping: unknown host www.du.edu.om

idp@idp1:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

On another Ubuntu server

```
root@grafana:~# ping www.du.edu.om
PING www.du.edu.om (23.238.34.19) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from client-23-238-34-19.hostwindsdns.com (23.238.34.19): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=329 ms
```

---

Does this look correct?

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
```

Comment: There is no such version as 16.4.6 do you mean 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Generally Google services will not respond to ping requests. It would be better to ping a less-trafficked server.

Regardless, let's see if we can't fix your `resolv.conf` issue:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Remove the symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   ***Note:** If the system says the file doesn't exist, just carry on to the next step.*
2. Create a symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
3. Reboot.

If you continue to have problems, update your question to include any errors that are reported